# Pressing Enter with Protractor in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor

I'm trying to test my Ionic App using end to end testing with protractor. I want to test my search input which currently searches when the enter key is pressed. How do I issue an enter command with protractor in Ionic?

I've tried this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

But I get:

```
Cannot find name 'protractor
```

Comment: What command do you use, how do you run your tests?

Comment: I'm using Jasmine to create the tests and Karma to run them, the command I'm running off the terminal is  npm run e2e

Comment: So, you are using `karma` to run protractor e2e tests? That could be the problem here, you should be using `protractor` to run protractor tests, karma is for running "unit" tests.